# Stripe node create customer not returning response

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am using the stripe nodejs api to create a customer as shown in their [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create). The customer gets created however Stripe does not return anything at all. I do have the function in a try/catch block but no error is caught. My code does not proceed at all and the customer id is not printed. I really am lost here.

Someone mentioned getting rid of `firebase-admin` which I was using. I removed it and it started working but then it stopped working.

```
const args = {
  name: "username",
  email: "email@email.com"
 }

try {
   const customer = await stripe.customers.create(args);
   console.log(customer.id)
} catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: If you use same code and execute directly without using `firebase-admin`, does it work?

Comment: @yuting, once I completely removed firebase-admin, it started working again for a couple of minutes but then it stopped.

Comment: @PapesTraore did you solve this problem? I am running into the same issue, just that I am using supabase instead of firebase

Comment: Vercel environment was the issue so I switched to AWS lambda.